# EA with Version Control- Get Latest Programmatically

Tags: enterprise-architect

I use EA API to get all latest changes form Version Control.

I loop on model packages that do not checked-out and get latest for each using `checkedOutPackage.VersionControlGetLatest(false);`

I get strange errors during runtime, such as:

**10999**
**Can't find matching ID**

**11030

Can't find matching ID** and so on...

Did someone encounter such error? What that means?

Answer (score 0):

The error usually means that EA can't find an element matching to the given ID.

Operations that return this type of error are `EA.Repository.getElementByID()`, `EA.Repository.getPackageByID()` etc.

Often this is due to data integrity issues in the repository. Do a **Project Integrity Check...** (Ctrl-shift-F9), let EA fix the errors and try again.

If that doesn't help then you'll have to debug your code to figure out what exactly is happening.